# Problem with Python-occ build - error when running make

Tags: python, linux, makefile, opencascade, pythonocc

I'm trying to install Python-occ under ubuntu 18.04.
After installing OCE successfully, I am trying to install py-occ. When I configure and I run cmake commande it is working :

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
--  
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "3.6.9") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found version "3.6.9") 
-- Build 64bit
-- Found SWIG: /usr/bin/swig3.0 (found suitable version "3.0.12", minimum required is "3.0.9") 
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so (found version "2.8.1") 
-- Platform:Unix
-- output_path: Unix/x86_64-Release-64
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc
```

but when I try to build using "make " I get the following error :

```
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
[  0%] Swig source
Scanning dependencies of target _UTL
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/UTLPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/UTLPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3788:9: fatal error: UTL.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<UTL.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/UTLPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/UTLPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_UTL.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
Scanning dependencies of target _CDF
Scanning dependencies of target _PCDM
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/CDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/PCDMPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/CDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3924:9: fatal error: CDF_TypeOfActivation.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<CDF_TypeOfActivation.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/CDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/CDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:252: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_CDF.dir/all] Error 2
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/PCDMPYTHON_wrap.cxx:3924:9: fatal error: PCDM_ReadWriter.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<PCDM_ReadWriter.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/PCDMPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/PCDMPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:215: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_PCDM.dir/all] Error 2
Scanning dependencies of target _TDF
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4013:9: fatal error: TDF_AttributeList.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<TDF_AttributeList.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDFPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:326: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_TDF.dir/all] Error 2
Scanning dependencies of target _TDataStd
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDataStdPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDataStdPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4055:9: fatal error: TDataStd_DataMapOfStringHArray1OfInteger.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<TDataStd_DataMapOfStringHArray1OfInteger.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDataStdPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/TDataStdPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:289: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_TDataStd.dir/all] Error 2
Scanning dependencies of target _IGESCAFControl
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/IGESCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/IGESCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4068:9: fatal error: IGESCAFControl_Reader.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<IGESCAFControl_Reader.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/IGESCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/IGESCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_IGESCAFControl.dir/all] Error 2
Scanning dependencies of target _XCAFPrs
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/XCAFPrsPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/XCAFPrsPYTHON_wrap.cxx:4931:9: fatal error: XCAFPrs_DataMapOfStyleShape.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<XCAFPrs_DataMapOfStyleShape.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/XCAFPrsPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/XCAFPrsPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_XCAFPrs.dir/all] Error 2
Scanning dependencies of target _STEPCAFControl
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/STEPCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
/scratch/rsayoud/Documents/Software_Packages/oce_folder/build/pyocc/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/STEPCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx:5582:9: fatal error: STEPCAFControl_DataMapOfPDExternFile.hxx: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include<STEPCAFControl_DataMapOfPDExternFile.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/build.make:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/STEPCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/Unix/x86_64-Release-64/STEPCAFControlPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_STEPCAFControl.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can not figure what is the problem, It seems like some files ( that normally should be generated during the cmake step) are missing. Do anyone encountered the same problem before? your suggestions will be very helpful.

This is the version I am using of python occ : https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core

and this is the oce I'm using : https://github.com/tpaviot/oce

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are several pieces of 'Python-occ' software. Please update your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67581947/edit .... to include a link to the source code you are trying to build

Comment: This is the version I am using of python occ : https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core                 and this is the oce I'm using : https://github.com/tpaviot/oce

Comment: OCC : `sudo pip3 install occ` or `pip3 install occ`